# Splitting a csv in to multiple csv's by common data in an assigned column - Python

Tags: python, bash, csv, scripting

AARRGG!!
I have a batch processing script to do a bunch of tasks in python, however I just can't get this part right. Essentially, a bunch of data is fed in to a csv, cleaned, a report is generated, and then finally the csv is split in to many smaller csv's by matching the category column. It should sort the data from that column, so group like entries, then create a csv for all like entries. However, the csv's it's generating is taking content from a different column. I am selecting Column 1 to sort by, yet it's sorting by column 3 currently.

Here's the code:
`

```
import pandas as pd

def print_column_options(df):
  # Print a numbered list of the columns in the DataFrame
  for i, column_name in enumerate(df.columns, start=1):
    print(f"{i}. {column_name}")

def get_column_name(df):
  num_columns = len(df.columns)
  column_number = int(input("Enter the number of the column to use for splitting the file: "))
  if column_number < 1 or column_number > num_columns:
    print(f"Error: columns are effed")
    return None
    return df.columns[column_number - 1]

def split_csv(filename, column_name, output_path="./"):
  # Read the input CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
  df = pd.read_csv(filename)

  # Split the DataFrame into multiple DataFrames based on the values in the specified column
  split_dfs = df.groupby(by=column_name, sort=False)

  # Save each split DataFrame to a separate CSV file
  for value, df in split_dfs:
    df.to_csv(output_path + value + ".csv", index=False)

# Prompt the user for the file path of the input CSV file
filename = "subscripts/output-cleaned.csv"

# Read the input CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

# Print the available column options
print("Column options:")
print_column_options(df)

# Prompt the user to select a column by number
column_name = get_column_name(df)

# Split the CSV file into multiple files based on the values in the specified column
split_csv(filename, column_name, output_path="subscripts/csvs-by-category/")

# Output a message indicating that the script has finished processing the data
print("Finished processing the data.")
```

`

I have completely rebuilt this from the ground up a few times. I recently switched to the pandas library because I just couldn't get anything to export with the standard csv libraries. I could paste the countless revisions I made between 9pm and 5am, but i'll spare you the agony and just leave it as "i tried quite a few things"

Comment: Your indentation for `def get_column_name(df):` function needs fixing.

Comment: If you are not looking for a `bash` answer please remove `bash` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since you identified [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), presumably you will consider a solution based on that.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="dummy.csv"
PREFIX="OutputPrefix"

cat >"${INPUT}" <<EnDoFiNpUt
col1_01,01_02,01_03,01_04,01_05,01_06,01_07,01_08
col1_02,02_02,02_03,02_04,02_05,02_06,02_07,02_08
col1_03,03_02,03_03,03_04,03_05,03_06,03_07,03_08
col1_04,04_02,04_03,04_04,04_05,04_06,04_07,04_08
col1_05,05_02,05_03,05_04,05_05,05_06,05_07,05_08
col1_06,06_02,06_03,06_04,06_05,06_06,06_07,06_08
col1_03,05_02,05_03,05_04,05_05,05_06,05_07,05_08
col1_03,01_02,01_03,01_04,01_05,01_06,01_07,01_08
col1_06,02_02,02_03,02_04,02_05,02_06,02_07,02_08
col1_06,04_02,04_03,04_04,04_05,04_06,04_07,04_08
col1_01,04_02,04_03,04_04,04_05,04_06,04_07,04_08
col1_01,02_02,02_03,02_04,02_05,02_06,02_07,02_08
col1_05,01_02,01_03,01_04,01_05,01_06,01_07,01_08
EnDoFiNpUt

cat "${INPUT}" |
awk -v pref="${PREFIX}" '{
    split( $0, dat, "," ) ;
    file=sprintf("%s__%s.csv", pref, dat[1] ) ;
    print $0 >file ;
}'
```

That single "**>**" for the print statement is counter-intuitive, but it will **create or append** to the specified file.

Doing wc -l on the output files shows the correct number of lines for each intended file:

```
ericthered:/0__WORK$ wc -l Output*
  3 OutputPrefix__col1_01.csv
  1 OutputPrefix__col1_02.csv
  3 OutputPrefix__col1_03.csv
  1 OutputPrefix__col1_04.csv
  2 OutputPrefix__col1_05.csv
  3 OutputPrefix__col1_06.csv
 13 total
ericthered:/0__WORK$
```

Comment: hey cool, thank you! I'll see if I can work that in